# Can't show Double from CoreData in UILabel inside a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In this table view (`override func tableView`), I show points of interests, some loaded by default, others by the user. I can retrieve the name of the managed object, but when try to show the position, it fails.

I can't show the latitude and longitude in the `TableViewCell`. If I use the `name` keyword the name appears. Maybe I should do some kind of conversion from numbers, but where?

I also got this warning:

> CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME.ArcheoPOI' for entity 'ArcheoPOI'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

This is my `NSManagedContext`

[image]

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

import CoreLocation

class AppiaTVC: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    var places : [NSManagedObject] = []

    let myLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //MARK : good way to set the reuse id of the cell
        //        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell") //alternative to put it in the
        //MARK : good way to set the table title
        title = "\"All the POI\""


    }





    //MARK: - Added for fetching data from CoreData
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //1
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!      //needed to handel mangedObject (saving and fetching entries)

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"ArcheoPOI")

        //3
        var error: NSError?

        let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

        if let results = fetchedResults {
            places = results
        } else {
            println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return places.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("appiaCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AppiaTVCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            //            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 143 / 255, green: 204 / 255, blue: 255 / 255, alpha: 1)
            //            cell.sweetTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 63 / 255, green: 159 / 255, blue: 255 / 255, alpha: 1)

        } else {
            //            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 63 / 255, green: 159 / 255, blue: 255 / 255, alpha: 1)
            //            cell.sweetTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 143 / 255, green: 204 / 255, blue: 255 / 255, alpha: 1)
        }


        let singlePlace = places[indexPath.row]
        //KVC is the only way to access data in CoreData (can't use a property) butwe could also use a more natural object-style person.name
        //        cell.textLabel!.text = singlePlace.valueForKey("name") as? String
        cell.cellNameLabel.text = singlePlace.valueForKey("name") as? String
        cell.cellLatitudeLabel.text = singlePlace.valueForKey("latitude") as? String //if I use "name" it works
        cell.cellLongitudeLabel.text = singlePlace.valueForKey("longitude") as? String //if I use "name" it works

        return cell
    }




    @IBAction func addPlaceButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "New place", message: "Add a new place", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            let textField = alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField
            self.saveName(textField.text) //self.names.append(textField.text)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
            (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alert,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)

    }




    //MARK: - save data to CoreData - this function is called by the addName button
    func saveName(name: String) {
        //1
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        //2
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ArcheoPOI", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)   //NSEntityDescription is required

        let place = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)


        myLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        let lat = myLocationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
        let lon = myLocationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
        myLocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        println("************************")
        println(lat)
        println(lon)
        println("************************")


        //3
        place.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        place.setValue(lat, forKey: "latitude")
        place.setValue(lon, forKey: "longitude")

        //4
        var error: NSError?
        if !managedContext.save(&error) {

            println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")

        }
        //5
        places.append(place)
    }




    //MARK - delete NSManagedObject
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        switch editingStyle {

        case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete:
            // remove the deleted item from the model
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let managedContext:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!


            managedContext.deleteObject(places[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
            places.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            managedContext.save(nil)

            //tableView.reloadData()
            // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        default:
            return

        }
    }




    @IBAction func BackButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
let latitude = singlePlace.valueForKey("latitude")
let longitude = singlePlace.valueForKey("longitude")
cell.cellLatitudeLabel.text = "\(latitude)" //if I use "name" it works
cell.cellLongitudeLabel.text = "\(longitude)" //if I use "name" it works
```

I also strongly encourage you to create a class which will manage your entity. You can find good instructions on how to do it [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-subclassing-nsmanagedobject--cms-21880). This tutorial is in objective-c but since then nothing has changed much ;)

You will then be able to call `singlePlace.latitutde` instead of using `valueForKey`,

Comment: problem with your code : Unexpected '"' character in string interpolation

Comment: thank you for help and tips, but I had to add "as! NSNumber". Is there a proper way to see and edit what I have in my coreData? I'd like to add many objects from a list via Xcode

Comment: Follow the tutorial which I referenced. It shows you how to easily create subclasses for your entities which will allow you to access the properties of your entities without use if valueForKey

Answer (score 0):

This  is for the CoreData warning you mentioned:

When view an entity on your .xcdatamodeld file, open the `Utilities` tab and look at the `Data Model inspector` section. There is a drop down list for `Module`. As of some of the newer Xcode 7 betas, it will say `Current Product Module` by default. Delete that and leave it blank. This should clear up your problem.

Comment: the only drop down menu I see is "parent entity"

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? It was a warning I've only seen since Xcode 7b3 or 7b4. If you use an earlier Xcode, then that drop down menu may not be there and the warning may be from something else.

Comment: Not the the beta, Xcode 6.4 maybe I should not use a struct and use 100% coreData, as suggested in the answer above...